# how to create basic html 5 page

Tags: html

Hi i am new for html5 can you tell me how do create html5 basic page.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> some body here</p>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell how do create this html page into html5 .

Thanks.

Comment: GO to  google and type html5 tag and starcture

Answer (score 3):

Given below is the standard html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
Content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  i am new for html5.

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTML5 file can be created by using the following tags

1. `<!DOCTYPE html>`: which tells the web-browser that the version of html used is html5.
2. `<html></html>`
3. `<head></head>`
4. `<title></title>`
5. `<body></body>`

or

type `!` in your 1st line of code and press enter which will return the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have suggested an edit for your post to make the HTML tags visible. Please make use of the formatting possibilities we provide next time. Also, I don't understand the part about typing `!` in the first line. This seems highly Editor-dependent to me.